# Using NULL in a where class of a bit column

Tags: sql

I have the following table structure

```
Id (PK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
IsAccepted (bit, null)
...
```

I am trying to return all the rows `where IsAccepted = NULL`

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Invitations]
WHERE IsAccepted = NULL
```

I do have some invitation with `IsAccepted = null` but the query won't return any.

Comment: `WHERE IsAccepted IS NULL`

Comment: You **cannot** apply regular comparison operators to `NULL` - you can **only** check `WHERE IsAccepted IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`